# Android trouble using variables declared in android.app.Application

Tags: android, global-variables

I am new to android. I have problem working with my application. I have some variables I need to keep track across various activities in my app. So I declared them in a class extending android.app.Application. Actually I thought that those variables would be alive only until the app is alive. If we close the app, thought they wouldn't be alive.

For eg: I have some variable "n" which I have declared in global context using class that extends android.app.Application. So I do some activities and finally when the app is about to complete and get exited, n is incremented to 7. So next time, when I try to newly run the app I see that n is still holding the value 7 but not 0 ( During the variable declaration in application class, I initialized it to 0) and it is incremented like 8,9...but not 1,2(what I expect to happen)..why is it holding the values even after the app is completed and exited? am I wrong about android.app.Application class?..so I want my app to keep track of variables only until the app is executed.. If the app completes and when it is newly run again I want to get it newly initialized(like n again initialized to 0)... how do I do that?

Comment: because the app being closed does not mean it is exited.

Comment: How do you close the application?

Comment: @Seraphim I just have finish() in all the activities...I thought no more activities left on the stack, app would get killed releasing all the resources..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android platform (and similarly on iOS) your app is not exited when you press back (or home) button. Your app is just brought to background, which is why your Application is still alive, thus holding variables you previously set. It is up to Android OS to decide when your app is really killed - and it is usually when OS needs to clear some system resources (usually memory).

You should design your app with this in mind.

So back to your situation - first you should check about [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). There are lifecycle methods like onPause, or onStop that you can override and reset your Application state as you like.

Comment: I thought having finish() in all the activities would serve the purpose..no more activities on the stack..app would get killed..So I was wrong.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

As told bt smitalm "your app is not exited when you press back ". To close app (and terminate it) first **unload all acitvities**, then execute:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: By "unloading" you mean finishing all the activities? and then wtiting System.exit(0)..r8?

Comment: System.exit(0) does indeed exit the application, but it is hacky since it kind of bypasses standard practices. It can be useful in some scenarios, but most of the time its best to be avoided and use Activity lifecycle methods correctly.

Comment: Yes, true. I have the "quit" button on my app and everything works fine. Take your decision.

Comment: which onStop()? in the application class?

Comment: No...the last activity that is going to be executed in my app..Wouldn't that work?

Comment: no ok... try it! just don't use onTerminate() in the application class

Answer (score 0):

As told above you can call `finish()` method on `onBackPressed()` method on each activity.
override `onBackPressed()` in each activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
        finish();
}
```